# how to decode nested json in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

i am having a json string like:

```
[
{
    "message": "Test+sms",
    "sender": "test",
    "billcredit": "0.00",
    "messageStatus": "DND",
    "sendondate": "2015-04-22 15:22:00",
    "provider": "aaaa"
},
{
    "message": "Test+sms",
    "sender": "test",
    "billcredit": "0.00",
    "messageStatus": "DND",
    "sendondate": "2015-04-22 15:22:00",
    "provider": "aaa"
},
{
    "message": "Test+sms",
    "sender": "test",
    "billcredit": "1.00",
    "messageStatus": "DELIVRD",
    "sendondate": "2015-04-22 15:22:00",
    "provider": "aaaa"
},
{
    "message": "Test+sms",
    "sender": "test",
    "billcredit": "1.00",
    "messageStatus": "DND REJECTED",
    "sendondate": "2015-04-22 15:22:00",
    "provider": "aaaa"
}
]
```

I try doing like this:

```
$objs = json_decode($data,true);
foreach ($objs as $obj){
$repor= $obj['messageStatus'];
echo $repor;
```

But its not working. Please anybody can help me to get rid out of this. Please help me to upload $repor sequentially in mysql.

Comment: It is not a valid json.

Comment: actually it is valid as i receive the same when i post a url.

Comment: Try to validate it in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: https://ideone.com/0VcF2k

Comment: @ManojKumar Thank you for your help if you can tell me how to update it a db maintaining the same sequence in db.. Not inserting only updating..

Answer (score 1):

```
Working Fine Now Check

$data='[{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22  15:22:00","provider":"aaaa"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22  15:22:00","provider":"aaa"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DELIVRD","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"aaaa"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DND REJECTED","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"aaaa"}]';

$objs = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($objs as $obj){
    $repor= $obj['messageStatus'];
    echo $repor." ";
}

I have placed only single quotation around json array. Nothing more.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }


    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's *almost* json, but not quite.

Try this:

```
$data = '{"messages":' . $data . '}';
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($decoded['messages'] as $message) {
  $messageStatus = $message['messageStatus'];
  echo $messageStatus;
}
```

Comment: Actually it might even be valid json as-is... when you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean?